# I created registration form through django forms.But its not rendring?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create blog app with django.I created registration form with django forms.In official django documentation for get request the code is form.classname().I also coded in that way.But its returning register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'?

```
 from django import forms

 class register(forms.Form):
   Email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
   Username = forms.CharField(label='Username', 
                                             max_length=100,required=True)
   Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),required=True)
   Confirm_Password = 
               forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(),required=True)
 views.py

 def register(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
         form = register(request.POST)
         email = form.cleaned_data['email']
         User_name=form.cleaned_data['User_name']
         Password1=form.cleaned_data['Password1']
         Password2=form.cleaned_data['Password2']
         if form.is_valid():
             if User.objects.filter(username=User_name).exists():
                 messages.info(request,'Username Taken')
                 return redirect('register')
             elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                 messages.info(request,'Email Taken')
                 return redirect('register')
             else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=User_name,
                                        password=Password1,email=email)
                user.save();
                return redirect('/')
         else:
             messages.info(request,'Password Not Matching')
     else:
         form = register()
         return render(request,'register.html',{'form': form})

   models.py

   from django.db import models
   from django.conf import settings

   # Create your models here.
   class Post(models.Model):
       title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
       desc=models.TextField()
       date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
       author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                           to_field="username",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Showing error:register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your form name is the same as view name. Change name of form to something different.

I also noticed other mistakes:

- before accessing specific form fields you have to check its validity:

```
if form.is_valid():
    field1 = form.cleaned_data["field1"]
```

- Your form field names don't match with retrieving data using `form.cleaned_data["someFieldName"]`

Comment: One more Doubt.How to design Django forms like we do with css